# for $S^{-1}A$-module $M$, $S^{-1}A\otimes_A M\to M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $A$ be commutative ring, and $S\subset A$ be multiplicatively closed set.

And let $M$ be $S^{-1}A$-module.

Now we have counit of adjunction of "change of rings"

$M\otimes_A S^{-1}A\to M$

I think this is isomorphism of $S^{-1}A$-module, is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now counit $\varphi: M\otimes_A S^{-1}A\to M$ is $\varphi(x\otimes \frac{a}{s})=\frac{ax}{s}.$

Let $\psi:M\to M\otimes_A S^{-1}A$ be $\psi(x):=x\otimes 1$.

Now $\psi$ is morphism of $S^{-1}A$-module.
Indeed, for any $a\in A, s\in S, x\in N,$

$s \psi(\frac{a}{s}x)=s(\frac{a}{s}x\otimes 1)=\frac{a}{s}x\otimes s=ax\otimes 1=x\otimes a=a(x\otimes 1)=a\psi(x)=s(\frac{a}{s}\psi(x)). $

multiply $s$, we get $\psi(\frac{a}{s}x)=\frac{a}{s}\psi(x)$, so $\psi$ is morphism of $S^{-1}A$-module.

Morover, $\varphi(\psi(x))=\varphi(x\otimes 1)=y. $

$\psi(\varphi(x\otimes\frac{a}{s}))=\psi(\frac{ax}{s})=\frac{ay}{s}\otimes 1=\frac{y}{s}\otimes a=\frac{1}{s}\cdot s(\frac{y}{s}\otimes a)=\frac{1}{s}(y\otimes a)=y\otimes \frac{a}{s}.$

From the above, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ is inverse morphism each other.